# how to select all users except for the current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i would like to list all users on an index page, apart from the current user. Im trying to make a 'people to follow' feature, and obviously the current user cant be on that list. my current code is below. Im using device, im assuming something like @users = User.where(user: != current_user).limit(5), or something like that.

tweets controller, index:

```
@users = User.all.limit(5)
```

Index page:

```
<h3 class="text-primary sides-title">Explore</h3>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <div class="user_card">
     <p class="users_username text-primary"><%= user.username %></p>
     <%=  cl_image_tag user.photo, height: 60, width: 60, crop: :fill, class: "users_photo" %>
     <%= link_to "Check'em out!", user_path(user), class: "user_button" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: User.where.not(id: current_user.id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User.where(user: != current_user)` is invalid syntax, for SQL comparison operators you can provide a string as an argument for `where`:

```
User.where('user_id != ?', current_user.id) # binding the argument provided
```

Or just `User.where.not(id: current_user.id)`

Comment: thanks that works! ive used the `User.where.not(id: current_user.id)`. But is there a way to add limit(5) to the end. ive tried but says invalid syntax.

Comment: Can you show what error you're having. How're you trying to add the limit?

Answer (score 0):

For **Rails 4+** notation:

`all` users except `current_user`

```
User.where.not(id: current_user.id)
```

**OR**

users except `current_user` with `limit`

```
User.where.not(id: current_user.id).limit(5)
```